# Centralize data at home for users

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, domain

In my house I would like to setup a sort of domain, I think. I have two or three desktops and would like to centralize my data per user. I would like to make each user login and all his items are displayed when he logs in, unlike now where the data is different over the three desktops.

What would I need to do to get this up and running with Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 is certainly one option

You can also [use Linux as a Primary Domain Controller](http://www.steve-lacey.com/2006/11/linux_as_a_wind). Popular distributions like Ubuntu are likely to have their own [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/samba-dc.html)

Comment: Hmm Linux is more command line though. I guess I'll do it with Windows Server.

Comment: The Samba Web Administration Tool (SWAT) has a domain controller wizard (i.e. GUI) but if you are uncomfortable with Linux, you should probably buy Windows.

Comment: Linux might be a stretch too far me, maybe in the future. I'll get to know Windows Server first.

Comment: Another option is the Small Business Server line. Probably more than what you are looking for though. SBS comes with Exchange and Sharepoint for the same price, but it looks like you won't need that functionality.